# Creating a list of all possible combinations

Tags: reactjs, sql, database, combinations

I'm trying to do the following.

I want to create a list of all possible relationships between certain things.

For example. There's Mary, Alice, June, Cindy, Elizabeth, Betty, Jax

I would like to create all possible combinations for a list like this:

- Mary, Alice
- Mary, June
- Mary Cindy
- Mary, Jax
- Mary, Alice, June
- Mary, Alice, Cindy
- Mary, Alice, Elizabeth
  ...
- Mary, Alice, Jax
- Mary, June, Cindy
- Mary, June, Elizabeth
  ...
- Mary, June, Jax
- Mary, Cindy, Elizabeth
- Mary, Cindy, Betty
- Mary, Cindy, Jax
  ...
- Mary, Alice, June, Cindy
- Mary, Alice, June, Elizabeth
- Mary, Alice, June, Betty
  ...
- Mary, Alice, June, Cindy, Elizabeth
- Mary, Alice, June, Cindy, Betty

Anyone know of a way to do this in either, SQL, Access, or C#? If there's another language out there that I can use on DB's I'd appreciate it a lot!

Thanks,
maria

Comment: All possible combinations till what? Twenty a row? Is `Mary, Mary` valid? Why is there no `Mary, Elisabeth`?

Comment: Why there is no `Mary` (just 1 name)? Is `Mary, Alice` the same as `Alice, Mary`?

Comment: @Oded - Mary, Mary would not be valid in this case. Mary, Elizabeth would be valid, I just skipped over to the last combination in that 2 pair combo to Mary, Jax.

Comment: @Ypercube - I was looking for pairings. In this case I wanted to use Mary is the base and the subsequent names as pairings to the first name.

Comment: What DBMS please? I have a solution in SQL Server that could be ported to other DBMSes but it would be nice to know what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You may like recursive queries used by many modern DB servers for this.

ACCESS is not one of them :(

the following is a sample with [postres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html)

```
postgres=# with RECURSIVE y1(b,c,d) as (
postgres(#      with x1(a) as (
postgres(#              values('a')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values ('b')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values ('c')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values ('d')
postgres(#      )
postgres(#      select a,a,1
postgres(#      from x1
postgres(#      union all
postgres(#      select a||b,a,d+1
postgres(#      from x1
postgres(#              join y1 on (a < c)
postgres(# )
postgres-# select *
postgres-# from y1;
  b   | c | d
------+---+---
 a    | a | 1
 b    | b | 1
 c    | c | 1
 d    | d | 1
 ab   | a | 2
 ac   | a | 2
 ad   | a | 2
 bc   | b | 2
 bd   | b | 2
 cd   | c | 2
 abc  | a | 3
 abd  | a | 3
 acd  | a | 3
 bcd  | b | 3
 abcd | a | 4
(15 rows)


postgres=#
```

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, I am not familiar with postgres but I will look into this solution further.

Answer (score 2):

SQL can be very good for this sort of thing. It gets sticky if you want to go very wide, but if you knew you wanted all combinations of up to, say, five items:

```
DECLARE @things TABLE (n nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @things (n) VALUES ('Mary'),('Alice'),('June'),('Cindy'),('Elizabeth'),('Betty'),('Jax'), (null);

SELECT 
  ISNULL(t1.n + ',', '') 
  + ISNULL(t2.n + ',', '') 
  + ISNULL(t3.n+ ',', '') 
  + ISNULL(t4.n+ ',', '') 
  + ISNULL(t5.n, '') 
FROM @things AS t1
JOIN @things AS t2 ON 1=1
JOIN @things AS t3 ON 1=1
JOIN @things AS t4 ON 1=1
JOIN @things AS t5 ON 1=1
```

Comment: +1 Although you do have some clean-up for things that look like `Mary,Mary,Mary,Mary,Mary` when it should just be `Mary`. Also you should try just listing `@things` multiple times in the `FROM` clause without a `JOIN` condition.

Comment: @Yuck is right about the clean up. I'm just trying to help Maria get started. She might also want to get rid of some dangling commas. The multiple items in the FROM clause would work most of the time, but it's a style I find confusing to look at.

Comment: What you have is `FROM @things AS t1
CROSS JOIN @things AS t2 CROSS JOIN ...`

Comment: The `JOIN` might be useful though, for changing the FROM part into: `FROM @things AS t1 JOIN @things AS t2 ON t1.name < t2.name ...`

Comment: Trying the above right now, it's giving me a syntax error on the INSERT statement for a particular comma

Comment: The multiple value syntax is a newer feature in MS SQL. If it's not working on your SQL, you might have to do an INSERT statement for each value.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), then you could use the following in C#

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
{
    return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
           select
             from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
             where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
             select list[i];
}
```

Usage:

```
var names = new List<string> { "Mary", "Alice", "June", "Cindy", "Elizabeth", "Betty", "Jax" };
var powerSet = GetPowerSet(names);
foreach (var nameCollection in powerSet)
{
  foreach (var name in nameCollection)
  {
    Console.Write(name);
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You may want to remove any collections with less than 2 names, and also the complete set of names:

```
var cleaned = powerSet.Where(nc => nc.Count() > 1 && nc.Count() < names.Count());
```

Comment: hmm, trying this out right now as well will see if I can get it to work. Thank you devdigital. also, I'm utilizing VS 2008 any difference in the code for the above with this?

Comment: No that should be fine, you need .NET framework 3.5 or above, and you should add a using System.Linq; statement to the top of the source, and ensure you are referencing the System.Core assembly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a defined number of elements, say , Mary, Alice, June, Cindy, Elizabeth, Betty, Jax, 8 elements in this case, you could nest 8 loops to display every possible permutation of elements. If the number is unknown you would need a recursive function.

Comment: Thanks whitelionV I'll research further into recursive functions then.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of awkward but will do the trick, or write an SQL proc with nested loops for each name.

create a separate table for each name, example:

```
CREATE TABLE MARY(name VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO  MARY VALUES ("Mary");

{do the same for each different name and then}

SELECT * 
  FROM mary, 
       alice,
       june,
       cindy,
       elizabeth,
       betty,
       jax;
```

This will generate a Cartesian Product without duplicating any names!