# Efficient ways to count the number of times two items are ordered together

Tags: sql

I am currently stuck on a problem where I have to write a SQL query to count the number of times a pair of items is ordered together.

The table that I have at my disposal is something like:

```
ORDER_ID | PRODUCT_ID |    QUANTITY    
1               1             10
1               2             20
1               3             10
2               1             10
2               2             20
3               3             50
4               2             10
```

I am looking to write a SQL query that can, for every unique pair of items, count the number of times they were ordered together and tell me the quantities when they were in the same order.

The resulting table should look like:

```
   PRODUCT_ID_1 | PRODUCT_ID_2 | NUM_JOINT_ORDERS | SUM_QUANTITY_1 | SUM_QUANTITY__2    
    1               2             2                   20                 40 
    1               3             1                   10                 10
    2               3             1                   20                 10
```

Some things to exploit are that:

1. Some orders only contain 1 item and so are not relevant in counting the pairwise relationship (not sure how to exclude these but maybe it makes sense to filter them first)
2. We only need to list the pairwise relationship once in the final table (so maybe a WHERE PRODUCT_ID_1 < PRODUCT_ID_2)

There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127728/how-to-count-all-combined-occurrences-in-sql), though I have reposted the question because

1. I really want to know the fastest way to do this since my original table is huge and my computational resources are limited, and
2. in this case I only have a single table and no table that lists the number.

Comment: What do you have in the way of indexes?  partitions?

Comment: @EvilTeach Partition-wise, I have a ORDER_DATE, and PRODUCT_CATEGORY type columns... Index-wise, I have ORDER_ID (the key to the database is really PRODUCT_ID and ORDER_ID). If it helps, I only need cross-relationships for items within the same product category (currently doing this before the query).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following approach, which gives you the result shown above.

```
select
  PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2, count(*), sum(QUANTITY1), sum(QUANTITY2)
from (
  select
    T1.PRODUCT_ID AS PRODUCT1, 
    T2.PRODUCT_ID AS PRODUCT2, 
    T1.QUANTITY AS QUANTITY1, 
    T2.QUANTITY AS QUANTITY2
  from TABLE as T1, TABLE as T2
  where T1.ORDER_ID=T2.ORDER_ID
  and T1.PRODUCT_ID<T2.PRODUCT_ID
)
group by PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2
```

Comment: Had the same thing.  You typed faster.